# Does the location of "main buttons" affect usability?

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, user-expectation, layout, design-patterns

Here we have Meta Stack Exchange:

[image: MSE]

The "Ask Question" button is part of the "search results" group. Could this possible confuse users? Should site-wide "main" buttons always be placed on the header bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I think it could confuse users, but difficult to say without usability testing with end-users. You'll definitely want to avoid hard-and-fast rules like *"site-wide "main" buttons should **always** be placed on the header bar"* ... no, "always" is too strong, but looking at established design patterns you'll generally find that action buttons, *e.g.,* "Ask Question" are found **below** search, not above as you have here. Sticking to common conventions is better for usability, so I would make that adjustment.